# What does compact set mean in the space $C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with the compact-open topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am considering the space $C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the compact-open topology. I know that with this topology, $f_n \to f$ if and only if $\sup_{|x|<K}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ for any $K>0$.

I want to know what a compact set looks like in the space $C_0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. In general, I know that the topology gives what open sets mean and thus we can know what a compact set is. However, I have difficulties to understand what a compact set is in this space.

Comment: You should read about the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.